# I want to use the cor() function but output says 'y' must be numeric. Problem is, it is numeric

Tags: r, correlation, numeric

I've reading data from an xlsx file.  My read code start off like this:

```
ecommerce<-read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Thomas Rhee\\Documents\\GGU\\GGU Fall 2018\\Tools for Business Analytics\\Final Project\\ecommerce.xlsx", sheet = "data", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE, col = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
attach(ecommerce)
names(ecommerce)
```

One of the columns is "price".  It looks like this:

```
price
<chr>
329.98  
324.83999999999997  
324.83  
350 
308 
310
```

I used the `sapply` to find out my 'price' column's class is character. I use the following code to convert it into numeric:

```
ecommerce$price <- as.numeric(as.character(ecommerce$price))
```

I checked again and it worked. I tried typing the following and get this output:

```
cor(rank, price)
```

> Error in cor(rank, price) : 'y' must be numeric

I'm lost. I'm also a beginner at this, so I'm open to suggestions here.  Please dumb it down for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example why you should not use `attach`.

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:3)
attach(d)
x ## now available because of attach
# [1] 1 2 3

d$x <- LETTERS[1:3]
x ## however this still refers to the original values of d$x
# [1] 1 2 3
d$x
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

That means, you changed your original data in the data frame, but in your `cor(.)` call you reference the original one (the one which was attached)

So to solve your issue, drop the `attach` command and specify the columns directly (after you have transformed them to a numeric):

```
cor(ecommerce$rank, ecommerce$price)
```

---

Technically, you could re-attach `ecommerce` again, after you changed it, but because of these issues I would strongly dis-encourage you to use `attach` at all.